# Polygon coordinates changed/edited/moved event (Google Maps V3)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Since Google maps v3.11, it's possible to set the `draggable` property onto the `Polygon`, `Circle` and `Rectangle`. eg, `new google.maps.Polygon({ draggable: true })`.

For `Circle` and `Rectangle`, there are events like `radius_changed`,`center_changed` and `bounds_changed` for us to subscribe when there is any change.

But for `Polygon`, we can only subscribe the `set_at`,`insert_at` and `remove_at` events of `polygon.getPath()`.

So, there will be a problem after I dragged the polygon, the position of the polygon had been changed/edited/moved, but no event to listen for this changes.

Comment: geocodezip, your example is very nice (http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_polygon-simple_draggableEditable.html); one comment is that google maps polygons are self-closing, so the way the example works now, your triangle has four vertices ;-) but that is besides the point of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about the "dragend" event?

That [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_polygon-simple_draggable.html)

Comment: thanks! i don't even know there are `dragstart` `drag` `dragend` for polygon.

Comment: i have one more question. after dragged a polygon, the `set_at` `insert_at` `remove_at` events are no longer receive any callback. do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe you need to add them to the polygon again?

Comment: yes,i added the listener again to solve the problem.but not very sure why the listener stop working after drag, maybe the path  object inside polygon has been changed?

Comment: It [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_polygon-simple_draggableEditable.html) without adding it again.

Comment: it seems because you are using `v3.exp` and i'm using `v3.11`

Comment: this doesn't appear to be in the official documentation,  are we expecting these events to continue being available?

Comment: @chrismarx They are documented, its just hard to find: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#dragging_events

Answer (score 11):

There is a better way to achive this, if you want to listen to changes on the path position and new points into the path, here is the code:

```
place_polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({/*...*/});
var place_polygon_path = place_polygon.getPath()
google.maps.event.addListener(place_polygon_path, 'set_at', polygonChanged);
google.maps.event.addListener(place_polygon_path, 'insert_at', polygonChanged);

function polygonChanged(){
    console.log('Changed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer mentioned we could use `dragstart` / `dragend` events to get the initial and last positions during drag and then update update the polygon's path coordinates (`polygonPath`).

We could do something like this:

```
let posInit: ILatLng;
let posLast: ILatLng;

this.area.addListener('dragstart', (event) => {
  posInit = event.latLng.toJSON();
});
this.area.addListener('dragend', (event) => {
  posLast = event.latLng.toJSON();
  polygonPath.forEach((p) => {
    p.lat += posLast.lat - posInit.lat;
    p.lng += posLast.lng - posInit.lng;
  });
});
```